# Database is overwriting. Last entry from json is written in database and all other entry is overwritten. Showing only last Entry of Json File

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

```
PlayerService
```

this is srvice class of my boot app.

package io.anuj.springbootquickstart.topic;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PlayerService {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRespository playerRespository;
    //  private List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(
    //          new Topic("Spring","Spring Framework","SpringFramework Description"),
    //          new Topic("Core","Core Framework","CoreFramework Description"),
    //          new Topic("JavaScript","JavaScript Framework","JavaScript Description")));
    public List<Player> getAllPlayer(){
        List<Player> player = new ArrayList();
        playerRespository.findAll()
        .forEach(player::add); //lambda expressions
        return player;
    }
    public Player getPlayer(Long id){
        //return topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id).findFirst().get());
        return playerRespository.findOne(id);
    }
    public void addPlayer(Player player) {

        playerRespository.save(player);

    }
    public void updatePlayer(Long id, Player player) {
        playerRespository.save(player);

    }
    public void deletePlayer(Long id) {
        //topics.removeIf(t -> t.getId().equals(id));
        playerRespository.delete(id);
    }

}



PLayerRepository
```

this is player repository of my app.
    package io.anuj.springbootquickstart.topic;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PlayerRespository extends CrudRepository <Player, Long>{




    //crud repository-logic of any entity class
    //getallTopic()
    //gettopic(string id)
    //update topic(topic t)
    //deletetopic(string id)


}



PLayerController
```

this is player controller

```
package io.anuj.springbootquickstart.topic;


import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
//wherever rest controller is written it will give json as output send back as a HTTP response
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerService playerService;
    //get request by default
        @RequestMapping("/player")
        public List<Player> getallPlayer(){
            return playerService.getAllPlayer();
            }

    //get request
    @RequestMapping("/player/{id}")
    public Player getPlayer(@PathVariable Long id){
        return  playerService.getPlayer(id);
    }
    //
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value= "/getplayer")
    public void addAllPlayer(){

        Player player = new Player();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object ob = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/bridgeit/Desktop/P.D-anuj/Json/newPlayerInfo.json"));
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) ob;

            JSONArray data = (JSONArray) object.get("Playersinfo");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) 
            {
                JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) data.get(i);


                Object nameObj = itemObj.get("player_name");
                String playerName = (String) nameObj;
                player.setPlayer_name(playerName);

                Object imgObject = itemObj.get("player_img_url");
                String playerPic = (String) imgObject;
                player.setPlayer_img_url(playerPic);

                Object roleObj = itemObj.get("player_role");
                String roleName = (String) roleObj;
                player.setPlayer_role(roleName);

                Object battingStyleObj = itemObj.get("player_batting_style");
                String battingStyleName = (String) battingStyleObj;
                player.setPlayer_batting_style(battingStyleName);

                Object bowlingObj = itemObj.get("player_bowling_style");
                String bowlingName = (String) bowlingObj;
                player.setPlayer_bowling_style(bowlingName);

                Object nationalityObj = itemObj.get("player_nationality");
                String nationalityName = (String) nationalityObj;
                player.setPlayer_nationality(nationalityName);

                Object dobObj = itemObj.get("player_dob");
                String dobName = (String) dobObj;
                player.setPlayer_dob(dobName);

                Object teamIdObj = itemObj.get("team_id");
                String teamIdName = (String) teamIdObj;
                player.setTeam_id(teamIdName);


                playerService.addPlayer(player);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
    /*@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value= "/player/{id}")
    public void updatePlayer(@RequestBody Player player,@PathVariable String id){
        playerService.updatePlayer(id,player);
    }
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value= "/player/{id}")
    public void deletePlayer(@PathVariable String id){
        playerService.deletePlayer(id);
    }*/
}

this is POJO class
Player.java
package io.anuj.springbootquickstart.topic;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
/*@Table(name = "Player")*/
public class Player {
    /*@Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gene", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gene")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;*/

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "gene", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gene")
    private long id;
    private String team_id;
    /*@Column(name = "name")*/
    private String player_name;
    /*@Column(name = "display_picture")*/
    private String player_img_url;
    /*@Column(name = "role")*/
    private String player_role;
public Player(long id, String team_id, String player_name, String player_img_url, String player_role,
            String player_batting_style, String player_bowling_style, String player_nationality, String player_dob) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.team_id = team_id;
        this.player_name = player_name;
        this.player_img_url = player_img_url;
        this.player_role = player_role;
        this.player_batting_style = player_batting_style;
        this.player_bowling_style = player_bowling_style;
        this.player_nationality = player_nationality;
        this.player_dob = player_dob;
    }


    /*  @Column(name = "batting_style")*/
    private String player_batting_style;
    /*@Column(name = "bowling_style")*/
    private String player_bowling_style;
    /*@Column(name = "nationality")*/
    private String player_nationality;
    /*@Column(name = "dob")*/
    private String player_dob;
    /*@Column(name = "teamId")*/


    public Player(){
    }











    public String getTeam_id() {
        return team_id;
    }




    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }











    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }











    public void setTeam_id(String team_id) {
        this.team_id = team_id;
    }


    public String getPlayer_name() {
        return player_name;
    }


    public void setPlayer_name(String player_name) {
        this.player_name = player_name;
    }


    public String getPlayer_img_url() {
        return player_img_url;
    }


    public void setPlayer_img_url(String player_img_url) {
        this.player_img_url = player_img_url;
    }


    public String getPlayer_role() {
        return player_role;
    }


    public void setPlayer_role(String player_role) {
        this.player_role = player_role;
    }


    public String getPlayer_batting_style() {
        return player_batting_style;
    }


    public void setPlayer_batting_style(String player_batting_style) {
        this.player_batting_style = player_batting_style;
    }


    public String getPlayer_bowling_style() {
        return player_bowling_style;
    }


    public void setPlayer_bowling_style(String player_bowling_style) {
        this.player_bowling_style = player_bowling_style;
    }


    public String getPlayer_nationality() {
        return player_nationality;
    }


    public void setPlayer_nationality(String player_nationality) {
        this.player_nationality = player_nationality;
    }


    public String getPlayer_dob() {
        return player_dob;
    }


    public void setPlayer_dob(String player_dob) {
        this.player_dob = player_dob;
    }

    /*public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }*/








    /*public Player(Long id, String team_id, String player_name, String player_img_url, String player_role,
            String player_batting_style, String player_bowling_style, String player_nationality, String player_dob) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.team_id = team_id;
        this.player_name = player_name;
        this.player_img_url = player_img_url;
        this.player_role = player_role;
        this.player_batting_style = player_batting_style;
        this.player_bowling_style = player_bowling_style;
        this.player_nationality = player_nationality;
        this.player_dob = player_dob;
    }
*/
}
```

When i execute from json file it shows only last entry of json file. JSON file contains around 150 players but in databse is shows only last entry of the player. i think all the data is getting overwritten. Only last entry is shown of that json file in database. That is last player. Only one player which is last in json is there in database.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to tell because you have a lot of commented out code that makes things harder to follow, but I think it is because of where you are creating the `Player` in your controller. Since you're doing this:

`Player player = new Player()`

outside of the loop, and Java is pass by value of reference, after the first time you `addPlayer`, you're just updating the same player with new data each time. You could confirm this if you simply debug your code and see if `player` has an ID after the first save call.

You'd probably want to do this to fix it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Player player = new Player();
    // rest of your code here
}
```